# Changing email for iOS Firebase user authenticated with email link

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have an iOS app that uses Firebase, signs users in anonymously initially and then allows them to later add an email address, which is linked to the Firebase user using a call to:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential)
```

This all works fine but I'm now running into the issue of being unable to update that user's email.  I assumed this would work by simply sending another email link to the new email, then calling linkAndRetrieveData with the new credentials.

This, however, gives me a FIRAuthErrorCodeProviderAlreadyLinked error, because the user already has an email address.  I would've expected it to just overwrite the existing email.  I then tried/considered to solutions:

1. Unlink the email provider, then relink with the new credentials.  First, this seems impossible since the stated "providerId" for an email-link-authenticated user is "Firebase", and when I feed that into unlink it fails.  Second, this is bug prone because you could successfully unlink the first email and then have the link of the new email fail.
2. Use the provided "updateEmail" method - this doesn't work because it assumes email/password authentication, and I'm using email link authentication.  Even if this did work, it would mean having an unverified email.

So I'm wondering how to do this, or if it's actually possible that this isn't supported at all.  I can't believe this wouldn't be supported since it seems like a very common issue and basically makes email link authentication a nonstarter.

Answer (score 2):

updateEmail() is the method to change email for signed in user, no matter how the user was created or authenticated. You are right that the new email address would become unverified. The sendEmailVerification() method can then be triggered to send a verification email to the user, so they can verify the email address.

Comment: Note that this approach also has some bad states that are almost prohibitive - e.g., user makes typo in email change, then loses phone and has no way to recover data despite having verified an email previously.  Are you on the Google Firestore team?  Can you confirm that this is the only approach and that there's no way to mitigate potential data loss here (short of changing the auth method)?

Comment: The issue we're seeing is that, when we originally authenticate a user anonymously, then use email link authentication, the call to linkAndRetrieveData works, but Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified is false.  This issue is ok if we send the email with "sendSignInLink" (i.e., the first time, when the anonymous use has no email attached) because the email doesn't get set for the anonymous user until after the ilnk - i.e., we know it's verified even if it says it's not.  But in the updateEmail case, we have no idea whether the email is verified anymore.

Comment: So can you confirm that for an initially anonymous user the right flow is:

1.) Auth.auth().sendSignInLink - first time use wants to de-anonymize
2.) Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link) - check whether it's sign in
3.) Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData - link credentials
4.) Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail - if user wants to change email
5.) Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification - verify changed email
6.) Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData - call this again?

And if this is the right, and the calls aren't erroring, why isEmailVerified false?

Comment: As far as I can quickly see most use-cases can be implemented, although maybe on all with the client SDKs. If users have an unverified email address they can recover their password. If the email address is incorrect, they can sign in with the other provider and fix it. If that doesn't work for your use-case you can fix their email address through the Admin SDK. If you find a use-case that isn't covered, I'd suggest [filing a bug report or feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`providerID` for an email link user should be `"emailLink"`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthProvider.html#EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD) (Android link, since I couldn't find the iOS version quickly, and the values come from the server anyway).

But note that a linked account will always have a top-level provider of `"firebase"`, and then have the actual values of the linked accounts in the `UserInfo` elements of the [provider array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#providerdata).

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply Frank.  I take it that you would advocate unlinking as the right approach here - even though it does potentially create a bad state where the user could end up with no email?  One common case in which this could happen is if the new email is already linked to an existing account, and indeed it seems like in this case it's the "provider already linked" error that gets thrown upon the link call (if instead it prioritized notifying me that the email was in use for another user with the initial error, then I could stop and handle the case before the unlink).

Comment: I've never dealt with the scenario, so have no opinion on what's best. But unlinking should be possible, given that I expect there to be an entry with the correct providerId in the array.

Comment: So I dug into fixing this, and it turns out this doesn't work - when I pass in "emailLink" the unlink still fails.  Notably, when I iterate through the UserInfo array, there is only one object, and it has provider ID "password" - again this was linked using passwordless authentication.  And "password" doesn't work when passed into the unlink call either.  So I've tried "emailLink", "password", "Firebase", and "firebase" and they all fail with "User was not linked to an account with the given provider."

Comment: Note that I've also tried the two relevant variable directly:  EmailAuthProviderID ("password") from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants#/c:@FIREmailAuthProviderID

There's also EmailLinkAuthSignInMethod ("emailLink") from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants#/c:@FIREmailLinkAuthSignInMethod which unsurprisingly doesn't work since it's not a provider id.

Comment: Hi Frank - is there any chance you can respond to the comments on this question, in particular on the upvoted answer above if you agree that it's the right approach?  Is updateEmail the Google-endorsed approach, and if so can you explain how to handle the dynamic link?  We've now invested months into implementing our app with Firestore and are stuck on this issue.

Comment: Jin Lui is a lead engineer on Firebase Authentication, so his answer should be authoritative.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please ping him to respond to the questions above?  Right now there is simply not enough documentation for passwordless/email link authentication on iOS, changing email and verifying is core functionality and you are abandoning developers who have invested in Firebase Authentication.  My question is simply how to verify an email change, I've tried every API call I can find and, again, in the passwordless case email verification is crucial because otherwise you don't know if the user's data is at risk of being orphaned.